# falcon-autocrud: how to handle unique rows?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, falconframework

I want to create a simple app with Falcon that is able to handle small sqlite database with `hostname`: `ip` records. I want to be able to replace rows in sqlite, so I decide that `hostname` is unique field. I have a `model.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()
DB_URI = 'sqlite:///clients.db'

class Client(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'clients'
    id      = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hostname    = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    ip      = Column(String(50))
```

My simple `resources.py`:

```
from falcon_autocrud.resource import CollectionResource, SingleResource
from models import *

class ClientCollectionResource(CollectionResource):
    model = Client
    methods = ['GET', 'POST']
```

When I make a POST-request with updated information about `hostname`:`ip` i get an `Unique constraint violated` error:

```
req = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/clients', 
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
                    data=json.dumps({'hostname': 'laptop1', 'ip': '192.168.0.33'}));
req.content
>> b'{"title": "Conflict", "description": "Unique constraint violated"}'
```

Is there any way to replace existing records using `sqlalchemy`? Or maybe I was wrong choosing sqlite for these purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a REST-ful API you should *not* use `POST` to update existing resources, `POST` to a resource should only ever *create new resources*. `falcon-autocrud` is doing the right thing here.

Instead, use `PUT` on the individual resource (the `SingleResource` resource registered for `.../clients/<identifier>`) to alter existing resources.

If you use `hostname` in your `SingleResource` definition then `falcon-autocrud` should automatically use that column as the identifier (assuming that your `SingleResource` subclass is called `ClientResource`):

```
app.add_route('/clients/{hostname}', ClientResource(db_engine))
```

at which point you can `PUT` the new `ip` value directly with:

```
requests.put('http://localhost:8000/clients/laptop1', json={'ip': '192.168.0.33'})
```

(Note that `requests` supports JSON requests directly; the `json=` keyword argument is encoded to JSON for you, and the `Content-Type` header is set for you automatically when you use it).

You may want to limit what fields are returned for your `Client` objects. With a unique `hostname` you wouldn't want to confuse clients by also sending the primary key column. I'd limit the response fields by setting the `response_fields` attribute on your resource classes:

```
class ClientCollectionResource(CollectionResource):
    model = Client
    response_fields = ['hostname', 'ip']
    methods = ['GET', 'POST']

class ClientResource(SingleResource):
    model = Client
    response_fields = ['hostname', 'ip']
```

I see that `falcon-autocrud` doesn't yet support `PATCH` requests on the collection that alter existing resources (only `"op": "add"` is supported), otherwise that'd be another route to alter existing entries too.